# How to perfectly localize DatePicker, TimePicker in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, localization, custom-renderer

I want that when i change language in my app, the picker default text will change to localized text

[image]

The above picture is the default DatePicker (i changed only Cancel, Done Button Text)

if our user want to use Korean, the user should change language in our application settings

[image]

but it couldn' replace window's action bar part

[image]

in system settings, when i changed language

[image]

i can get a perfectly localized datepicker

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using App2.Resources;
using Java.Util;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Helpers;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using DatePicker = Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker), typeof(App2.Droid.CustomRenderer.LocalizationDatePicker))]
namespace App2.Droid.CustomRenderer
{
    public class LocalizationDatePicker : DatePickerRenderer
    {
        DatePickerDialog pickerDialog;
        private Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker datePicker;
        public LocalizationDatePicker(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            //Disposing
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                datePicker = null;
            }
            //Creating
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                datePicker = e.NewElement;
            }

            Locale locale = new Java.Util.Locale(LocalizationResourceManager.Current.CurrentCulture.Name.Split('-')[0]);
            Control.TextLocale = locale;
            Android.Content.Res.Configuration config = new Android.Content.Res.Configuration();
            config.SetLocale(locale);
            Locale.SetDefault(Locale.Category.Display, locale);
            Resources.Configuration.SetLocale(locale);
        }

        protected override DatePickerDialog CreateDatePickerDialog(int year, int month, int day)
        {
            pickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Context, (o, e) =>
            {
                datePicker.Date = new DateTime(e.Year, e.Month, e.DayOfMonth, 0, 0, 0, LocalizationResourceManager.Current.CurrentCulture.Calendar)  ;
                ((IElementController)datePicker).SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, false);
            }, year, month, day);
       
            //ok
            pickerDialog.SetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Positive, AppResources.Accept, OnDone);

            //cancel
            pickerDialog.SetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Negative, AppResources.Cancel, OnCancel);

            return pickerDialog;
        }

        private void OnCancel(object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
        {
            datePicker.Unfocus();
        }

        private void OnDone(object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
        {
            datePicker.Date = ((DatePickerDialog)sender).DatePicker.DateTime;
            datePicker.Unfocus();
        }
    }
}
```

this is LocalizedDatePicker CustomRenderer Code

Please inform how to customize Datepicker's Dialog ActionBar? header? or how to perfectly localize DatePicker

Comment: I used DevExpress Date Edit.  It use system language. İnformation : https://docs.devexpress.com/MobileControls/DevExpress.XamarinForms.Editors.DateEdit